# Excel units of time conversion

Tags: excel

I need to change a value of time from days:hours:minutes, into either hours with a decimal or minutes. My data comes up as `001:05:46` for example. I am having trouble with the leading zeros confusing excel. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to SO. We're going to need more information. Please provide an example of what you have and what you need and what you have tried to accomplish it. A few examples would even help more, especially if there are slight differences in the data.

Comment: If all of your time entries are in the format you've provided, this should work for you: `=LEFT(A1,3)*24+TIME(MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)`    However, if there are any variances in your data, we would need to see additional examples as Scott Holtzman already pointed out.

Comment: here's another formula that will work to get you the minutes based on your what you provided at face value: `=((VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))*24)*60)+(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2))*60)+(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))`

Comment: @tigeravatar To represent in terms of hours you multiplied the days by 24 but you also need to multiply the time by 24. You converted only part of the value.

Comment: How are you formatting the cells? I can't get the above formulas to work out just yet.

Comment: In the example from my post, 001 Days :05 Hours :46 minutes, needs to become 29.76 (hrs) or 1786 Minutes

Comment: So does this give you the result you want? `=LEFT(A1,3)*24+MID(A1,5,2)+RIGHT(A1,2)/60` All my cells are just formatted General. This assumes 3 digit day, colon, 2 digit hour, colon, and 2 digit minute with no trailing white space or other characters.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! You guys are better than my IT department!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your value to parse is formatted in `DDD:HH:MM` like `001:05:46`... There are a lot of ways to do this but here's a simple one. To convert into hours we need to take the days times 24 hours per day, add the hours, and add the minutes times 1 hour per 60 minutes:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)*24+MID(A1,5,2)+RIGHT(A1,2)/60
```

To get this value in terms of minutes we multiply by 60 minutes per hour. A possible modification of the original formula to reach this point would be:

```
=LEFT(A1,3)*24*60+MID(A1,5,2)*60+RIGHT(A1,2)
```